# How to Display "INVALID" if user inputs integer instead of String?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
System.out.println("\nEnter Your Name:");
         name=tc.next();
```

//How To Display "INVALID" if user inputs number instead of string?

I can't Solve it please help.

Comment: You have to handle exception manually with proper message?

Comment: `if (name.matches("\\d+"))`

Comment: but keep in mind: "2" -> this is a String. regex would indeed be the best way to put on restrictions

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this by using java.util.regex.Patternmatches

```
name = tc.next();
if(name.trim().matches("^[0-9]*$")){
   System.out.println("INVALID");
}
```

Note: trim() is used to avoid the white spaces if any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Character.isDigit() method to identify it is integer or not

```
String s;
if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)) == true)
          System.out.println("INVALID");
```

Comment: please format the code as .. code :)